# Total variation of sum of measures

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on proving that, given two signed measures $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ on $(X,M)$ that both omit either $\infty$ or $-\infty$,
$|\nu_1 + \nu_2| \leq |\nu_1|+|\nu_2|$ using the definition $|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^-$

However, I seem to be able to show that both sides are equal by using the fact that $\nu^+(E) = \nu(P \cap E)$ and $\nu^-(E) = -\nu(N \cap E)$ where $P \cup N$ is a Hahn decomposition of $X$.

My question: is this equality true?

Comment: No, it's not true. Try e.g. $\nu_2=-\nu_1$, where $\nu_1 \neq 0$ attains neither $\infty$, nor $-\infty$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, I found an alternative proof that gives the desired result so I'm glad to know that I was mistaken after all.